# Map Fn + Esc key to Esc key

Tags: macos, keyboard, utilities

I am using a PC keybroad on a Mac, the funniest thing is on this KB, to use the `Esc` key, I need to press `Fn + Esc`

So, are there any tool I can remap the keys such that I can use the `Esc` without the `Fn` key?

Comment: did you find a solution for it other than buying a new keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Fn is a function of the keyboard that modifies the key-codes being sent by the keyboard itself. Fn itself does not transmit any key-codes to the computer.

One option would be to try mapping the actual key (that is turned into Esc when Fn is pressed) to be the Esc key. I don't know of anything built into OS X that will do this across the board, however, you could try something like https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/

To be honest, good keyboards are so cheap these days you should probably just buy yourself a nice new keyboard that has a layout which suites your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

The `esc` key is marked on my keyboard with a ◻︎ (square icon), as it acts as the "home" button when used with a phone or tablet. Unforgivably, on a Mac, it does not send keypress events unless activated by the `fn` key.

I pried up the `esc` key and reattached it where the F5 key used to sit. Then I mapped the F5 key to 'escape' using [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).

So I had to relearn where the `esc` key sits, but at least I don't need to press two keys to escape.